# raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable

Tags: odoo-8

Can help me? i want to domain many2one field where id not show in other transaction

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('batch_id')
def _onchange_batch_id(self):
    if self:
        tempt=[]
        for record in self:
            tempt.extend([record.batch_id])

        culling = self.env['estate.nursery.cullinglinebatch'].search([('batch_id', '!=', list(tempt))])

        return {
             'domain': {'batch_id': [('batch_id','not in',culling),('qty_abnormal','>',0)]}

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In ODOO8/9 **search** method always return object not the Id of object.

```
culling = self.env['estate.nursery.cullinglinebatch'].search([('batch_id', '!=', list(tempt))])
```

Here `culling` is the object of model `'estate.nursery.cullinglinebatch`'

Your domain should be look like

```
 'domain': {'batch_id': [('batch_id','not in',culling.ids),('qty_abnormal','>',0)]}
```

here i have uses **culling.ids** instead of ***culling***.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: debug it this way, add logger inside _onchange_batch_id (before return),fetch the record of your branch using the same domain ,print  the result obtain by domain  in the log